# Does React Realm Native DB support encryption/description

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I read about this anouncement from facebook.

[introducing realm react native](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/)

But didn't see whether react realm native supports encryption/decryption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is best answered by the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the contributors to Realm React Native. Encryption isn't currently supported but it is something we will probably add in the future. I created an issue on github for this https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/279

In the meantime you may be able to use built in file protection to encrypt your realm files on iOS although this has not yet been tested.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Realm React Native now supports encryption, as per the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#encryption), and the [notes on github](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/pull/282).